# How to post to User's wall without the offline_access permission

Tags: facebook, offline, facebook-wall

we've created an application for helping law enforcement to find for missing people through Facebook. At this moment we were using the offline_access permission in order to post at the User's Wall in order to replicate a missing person case.

This is not a common application that is using the Wall to promote something, it's just for helping the law enforcement and the community.

Is there any way to do the same without asking the user to access our page? Our application is just doing this, and posting the case in a centralized page, nothing else.